# "Failed to get configuration" using Wolkenkit client in Mocha test through Node

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, domain-driven-design, wolkenkit

I am trying to interact with my Wolkenkit application through a Mocha test in Node.

Following the [tutorial on client connections](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/latest/reference/building-a-client/connecting-to-an-application/), when running the test, I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to get configuration.
  at ConfigurationWatcher.wentOffline (node_modules/wolkenkit-client/dist/ConfigurationWatcher.js:113:28)
  at /home/aef/Projects/experiments/wolkenkit_bullet/node_modules/wolkenkit-client/dist/ConfigurationWatcher.js:101:16
  at tryCatch (node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:409:12)
  at invokeCallback (node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:424:13)
  at publish (node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:398:7)
  at publishRejection (node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:339:3)
  at flush (node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:128:5)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

Any help on resolving this is highly appreciated.

I added the following dependencies in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "chai": "^4.2.0",
  "mocha": "^7.0.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "wolkenkit": "^3.1.2",
  "wolkenkit-client": "^3.1.0"
},
```

My test code looks like this:

```
'using strict';

const expect = require('chai').expect;
const wolkenkit = require('wolkenkit-client');

describe("wolkenkit app", () => {
    it("first test", async () => {
        const app = await wolkenkit.connect({host: 'local.wolkenkit.io', port: 3000});
    });
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While setting the environment variable within Node didn't work, the problem has been solved by setting `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` to `0` in the system environment like:

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Thanks to @mattwagl for pointing into the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

This error is probably caused by your local self signed certificate. The client is not able to connect to the backend since it does not trust this certificate. You can bypass this check using the `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` flag like this…

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;

suite('integration', () => {
  let application;

  suiteSetup(async () => {
    application = await wolkenkit.connect({ host: 'local.wolkenkit.io', port: 3000 });
  });
```

Another option would be to add the certificate to your trusted certificates.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't fix it. Neither setting the environment variable in code nor in the actual environment changed the error message.

Comment: Did the application start correctly? What is the output of `wolkenkit start`? Does it end with `Waiting for https://local.wolkenkit.io:3000/ to reply...` and `Running at https://local.wolkenkit.io:3000/`? If this is the output it means your application is running correctly. Then point your browser to `https://local.wolkenkit.io:3000/`. What do you see? You can use your browser to validate that the certificate is valid and it is also delivered correctly.

Comment: `wolkenkit start` works fine. I can access the wolkenkit-console locally, send commands manually and see projections being built. Still, the wolkenkit-client produces an error when I try to connect. Nothing about this is displayed in the output of `wolkenkit start`

Comment: Could you maybe post the whole test suite?

Comment: The posted was the entire test suite at that time. It was just my first steps trying to get a connection to Wolkenkit from Node.

Comment: We finally managed to solved it slightly differently than you had in mind. See @denyce answer.